# Plotting a Graph Using Matplotlib from a CSV file with multiple columns

Tags: python

I am trying to create a `boxplot` with the x label as Firm (5th column) and the y label as overall rating (1st column) from a csv file that is set up like this:

```
4,Missing,Missing,No opinion of CEO,ey,3.5,,3,4,3,2008,Current 
Employee,auditor,miami,Missing,unknown,audit
5,Recommends,Missing,Approves of CEO,ey,5,,5,5,5,2008,Current 
Employee,tax,tampa,Missing,unknown,tax
5,Recommends,Missing,Approves of CEO,ey,5,,5,4,5,2008,Current 
Employee,audit staff,tampa,Missing,associate,audit
```

From this, I would like to extract the overall rating column and firm column to plot this on a boxplot. Here is the code I have tried so far that has not worked:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv
x=[]
y=[]
with open('Ratings.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    bplot1 = axes[0].boxplot(all_data,vert=True,patch_artist=True)
    bplot2 = axes[1].boxplot(all_data,vert=True,patch_artist=True)
colors = ['pink', 'lightblue', 'lightgreen']
for bplot in (bplot1, bplot2):
    for patch, color in zip(bplot['boxes'], colors):
        patch.set_facecolor(color)
    plt.plot(x,y, marker='o')
plt.title('Overall Rating Based on Firm')
plt.xlabel('Firm')
plt.ylabel('Overall Rating')
plt.show()
```

Comment: How did it not work? is the error in reading the data, or plotting?

Comment: It seems like it is an error in plotting the data

Comment: Yeah, I copy/pasted it and it seems variable name `axes` is not defined. Perhaps you should add in a line to create this variable (probably with `plt.subplot()`?)

Comment: add `fig, axes = plt.subplot(nx,ny)` after opening the CSV File. In your case `nx =1` and `ny = 2` should be the values, but I don't know how you want your subplots to look.